# Video Call with subtitles in flutter

Tags: flutter, speech-to-text, agora.io

I am using Agora for video calling functionality but know I want the audio to be converted into subtitles in real time but I cannot access audio from agora SDK and give that audio to speech-to-text API to convert in Flutter. So is there a way to do that